# Does Safari for iOS 4.2.1 support WebGL?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Does iOS 4.2.1, the latest release at the time of this question, support WebGL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at this point, no. WebKit, that which Safari for Mac OS and iOS are both based on, is supposed to support WebGL but I have yet to be able to get it work properly on Mac OS 10.6, much less iOS. I get the impression the whole thing is too new (relatively) for proper support.

Answer (score 1):

WebGL resources:

- http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page
- http://www.scriptol.com/programming/webgl.php
- http://learningwebgl.com/blog/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL
- http://planet-webgl.org/

Looks like its only in Webkit, and even then you have to enable it:
More info: http://webkit.org/blog/603/webgl-now-available-in-webkit-nightlies/

Comment: I tried enabling it and I still get an error from all of the WebGL demo sites. I think there are still kinks to work out.

Comment: Maybe try the firefox beta as an alternative.

Comment: Firefox for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I would not get your hopes up of iOs ever supporting WebGL. Not only because exposing the video drivers to untrusted parties poses a security risk. It would also give game developers a way to circumvent the app store for distributing games. Same reason you will never see the flash support extend beyond anything but video.

Comment: Huh? There's no Flash support on iOS at all.

Comment: Flash Media Server 4.5 will reencode flash video to be iOs compatible. http://www.gizmag.com/adobe-flash-ios/19790/